# Alternating odd harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can't seem to find if this sum is known. I'm looking for the sum

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}}=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\dots$$

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  It is a well known series.  A web search should find it.

Comment: You mean other than googling? or what have I tried in order to solve it?

Comment: Hint: $$\int\frac1{1+x^2}\,dx$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Do you recognize this power series? Can you evaluate it at a particular value of $x$ that's in the interval of convergence?
$$
x - \frac{1}{3}x^3 + \frac{1}{5}x^5 - \frac{1}{7}x^7 + \cdots{}
$$

Comment: Taylor series of arctan. Got it thanks for your help